# Link inside Bootstrap accordion header

Tags: bootstrap-4, hyperlink, accordion

Is there a way to include a link to the header of a bootstrap accordion? Adding `<a href>Link</a>` breaks the accordion for me. The link would go to the linked page but clicking anywhere else on the header would open the accordion as normal. Pretty much the same as this unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866278/url-link-inside-bootstrap-accordion-header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to click on "Click me".

See the snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g0msw4up/).

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Click me</a>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the first accordion panel. This panel is shown by default, thanks to the <code>.show</code> class.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, interestingly the problem was that my header needed to contain <button> inside to work. Previously it contained <a role="button">which turned out to be the problem.

Comment: "element a cannot be nested inside button"